# Unable to establish a connection with the SafariDriver when using Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safari, selenium-grid, safaridriver

I am facing an issue where the Selenium Grid hub on windows machine is not able to make a connection on mac machine for Safari browser. I see the browser open up but then an error message comes up:

```
[ 0.007s] [safaridriver.client] Requesting connection at ws://localhost:xxxxx…
[ 2.513s] [safaridriver.client] Unable to establish a connection with the SafariDriver
```

My Hub is set up on windows 7 machine. My node command on Mac machine 10.8:
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.xxx.xxx.xxx:4444/grid/register -port 5559 -browser browserName=safari`

Selenium Webdriver  2.39
Mac 10.8.5 Mountain Lion
Safari Version 6.0.5 (8536.30.1)

Can anyone please guide me here on what could be the issue? Initially I thought it is an issue with ports on MAC Machine but I had them opened as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I too got the same issue. But resolved it by providing PLATFORM name using DesiredCapabilities.

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
dc.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
```

And also you have to mention the PLATFORM while connecting to Selenium Grid.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar -role node -hub http://XXXX:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=safari,platform=MAC
```